# How do I change these into integers, divide them and then change them back into string?

Tags: python

I get this error when trying to run my code (using repl.it):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    y  = y.replace("e", "-", "")
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My code:

```
import random
a = str(random.randint(1,10))
b = str(random.randint(0,999999))
x = random.randint(0,10)
y =  (a + "," + (str(int(a) / int(b))))
y  = y.replace("e", "-", "")
if x < 5:
  print(a + "," + b)
else:
  print(y)
```

Comment: The third argument to [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a _number_, how many occurrences should be replaced.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `y.replace("e", "-", "")`?

Answer (score 0):

you could replace `y  = y.replace("e", "-", "")`

with `y = "".join([l if l not in ["e", "-"] else "" for l in y])` and get the same result.

```
import random
a = str(random.randint(1,10))
b = str(random.randint(0,999999))
x = random.randint(0,10)
y =  (a + "," + (str(int(a) / int(b))))
y = "".join([l if l not in ["e", "-"] else "" for l in y])
if x < 5:
  print(a + "," + b)
else:
  print(y)
```